# error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm realising a stack data structure. When I call `pop` function in main function, an error appeared. It phrases like this:

1. `stack.h:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'`
2. `stack.h:13: error: initializing argument 1 of 'int remove(const char*)`

'

And the problem is that I didn't write the remove function with a `char` or a `char*` type parameter. 
So I hope any of you can help me out of here. Thanks for the help!

```
template <typename T> 
class Stack : public Vector<T> {
public:
    Stack () {  Vector<T>(); }
    T pop() { return remove( this->size() - 1 ); } //stack.h:13
};

template <typename T> 
class Vector {
protected:
    int _size; 
    int _capacity;  
    T* _elem; 
    void shrink();   
public:    
    T remove ( int r ); 
    int remove ( int lo, int hi );  
};

template <typename T> 
int Vector<T>::remove ( int lo, int hi ) { 
    if(lo==hi) return 0;
    while( hi < _size ) _elem[ lo++ ] = _elem[ hi++ ];
    _size = lo; 
    shrink();
    return hi-lo; 
}

template <typename T> 
T Vector<T>::remove ( int r ) { 
    T e = _elem[r]; 
    remove ( r, r + 1 ); 
    return e; 
}
```

in main function,

```
Stack<int> S;
for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
     S.push(i+1);
}
S.pop();
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to think why people have invented newline.

Comment: Which line is line 13 of `stack.h`?

Comment: Posted code won't compile, there's no Vector defined.

Comment: @ST3 I have mordified the code

Comment: Please look at this : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51794/stl-stack-implementation

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I made a note on line 13 of stack.h

Comment: By the way, you have a (unrelated to your problem) bug in the `Vector<T>::remove(int, int)` function, where you set the size of the vector to `lo`.  What if you remove an item in the middle of the vector? Then the size would be incorrect.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i didn't post all code, i will try to consolidate  a verifialbe example. Thanks!

Comment: @RonakPatel that's helpful, thanks! i will try to rewrite the pop function!

Comment: @Robert   Thank you for your effort to reedit my post, it was a mess until your work. I will do better next time!

Comment: @Mansuro    Thank you for your effort to reedit my post, it was a mess until your work. I will do better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the base class `Vector<T>` depends on the template parameter, and so has a type that isn't known until the template is instantiated, unqualified name lookup doesn't look there. This means that your unqualified call to `remove` doesn't resolve to the base-class member, but to some other overload (probably [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove)).

Write `this->remove` or `Vector<T>::remove` to indicate that you're referring to a member.

Comment: Great!Thank you!A similar problem emerged when I called 'size' function, but the error phrased differently, so I considered 'pop' function as a totally different problem.Again, thank you for your notice!